# SAPUI5 TreeTable: User Interaction set to "true" when event fired by code

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, treetable

When selecting a row in my SAPUI5 tree table I have to make sure that

1. all existing selections are removed
2. check if selected row has children and if so, select the item and all its children

To do that I use a function that gets called on the rowSelectionChange-Event of my table:

```
onRowSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameters().userInteraction)
        var oTable = oEvent.getSource();
        var oObject = oEvent.getParameters().rowContext.getObject();
        var iIndex = oEvent.getParameters().rowIndex;

            // Check if row was selected or deselected
            if (oTable.isIndexSelected(iIndex)) {

                // Deselect other items
                oTable.clearSelection();
                // Select row again
                oTable.addSelectionInterval(iIndex, iIndex);

                // Check if object has children
                if (oObject.content) {
                    //Select child rows here
                } else {
                    // Do stuff
                }
            } else {
                // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the first thing I do is to check if the selection change's origin was an explicit user interaction, because, of course, clearing the selection and then adding the selection for the child rows will call the function again.

My problem is now, that when clearSelection() calls my function, the userInteraction-parameter is again set to true, despite not being an explicit user interaction. Am I missing something here?

Thank you!